# Exception occurs in ie8 when dynamically updating Knockoutjs template

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, knockout.js

I use ajax to retrieve a partial HTML document to use as a Knockout template.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/html" id="LoadingTemplate">Loading...</script>
<script type="text/html" data-bind="attr: {'id': DynamicTemplateID}, html: ContentHTML></script>

<div class="main-page" data-bind="template: TemplateID"></div>
```

Script (partial):

```
self.TemplateID = ko.observable("LoadingTemplate");
self.DynamicTemplateID = ko.observable(GenerateUUID());

self.ContentHTML = ko.observable();    
ko.computed(function () {
    var url = self.ContentURL();
    self.GetContent(url, function (html) {
        self.ContentHTML(html);
        self.TemplateID(self.DynamicTemplateID());
    });
});
```

1. Initially the `<div>` will show: 'Loading'
2. The `id` attribute of the dynamic template is set to the generated ID
3. `GetContent()` performs an ajax call to retrieve the content
4. When the ajax call finishes the callback function is called
5. The observable `ContentHTML` is updated with the html
6. The observable `TemplateID` is set to the generated ID
7. The `<div>` is updated by ko

In Firefox this works like a charm, but IE8 throws an exception: `Error: Unexpected call to method or property access.` while updating the dummy `<script>` tag with the loaded template.

The error is throw by `jQuery.html()`. First `elem.innerHTML = value;` fails, which is catched then `this.empty().append( value )` fails, which gives the exception.

Partial 'stack trace':

```
this.appendChild( elem );    => callback function in jquery.append (v1.7.2 line 5847)
jquery.domManip
jquery.append
jquery.html
ko.utils.setHtml
ko.bindingHandlers.html.update
ko.applyBindingsToNodeInternal
ko.dependentObservable.evaluateImmediate
```

What could be the problem? Is it there a (known) IE8 problem with updating `<script>` tags?
Is there another way to 'store' templates inside the html page for ko to use (I prefer to use the ko native templating!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it using [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/using-external-jquery-template-files.html) on knockmeout.net:

Updated HTML (removed the dynamic `<script>` tag):

```
<script type="text/html" id="LoadingTemplate">Loading...</script>
<div class="main-page" data-bind="template: TemplateID"></div>
```

Updated script (appends the script tag after download of the template):

```
self.TemplateID = ko.observable("LoadingTemplate");
self.dynamicTemplateID = GenerateUUID();

ko.computed(function () {
    var url = self.ContentURL();
    self.GetContent(url, function (html) {
        $("body").append('<script type="text/html" id="' + self.dynamicTemplateID + '">' + html + '</script>');

        self.TemplateID(self.dynamicTemplateID);
    });
});
```

This is a little bit less the ko-way but works across *all* browsers.